# Best 64 bit OS for Pi 3 without screen

Tags: pi-3, debian, headless, 64-bit

So I've been running my Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie Headless and I've run into some issues with the fact that Raspbian seems to be 32bit and MongoDB requires 64bit.

So I am looking for the **best (preferably Debian-based) 64bit OS** for my Pi3.

The catch: I do not own any screen that uses HDMI and I can't easily get one.

**Requirements:**

- should be easy on resources
- must install without a display or from another PC
- must be made ssh-capable without connecting a screen

Bonus points for when I can just reuse an image of my root partition.

Any suggested operating systems or installation tutorials?

Comment: have you considered something other than a Raspberry Pi? Banana Pi, Orange Pi, for example come with twice the RAM as the Raspberry, and the Banana comes with Octo-core cpu and a SATA port

Comment: having said that, what makes you think "mongodb requires 64bit" - have you tried `apt install mongodb-server`?

Comment: I already own the Pi, so ...

Comment: As to MongoDB: apt-get installs 2.4, but all driver's support only versions 2.6 and newer, which for some reason require 64 bit

Comment: @JaromandaX There are a number of aarch64 distros for the Pi, I believe (e.g., Fedora).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
This answer is outdated. [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) is released as stable version and still only available as 32 bit version.

---

The next coming version in debian is **buster** and it is now the testing version. As far as I know it will provide a 64 bit version of Raspbian. You can try to use it. With a quick search I found at [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=203854):

> This works very well to install debian buster on RPi 3 B+ using arm64 and kernel 4.18

Comment: [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/) has been released now but it's still only a 32 bit OS. As far as I understand the quote (and the article that is linked in that forum), the quote isn't about Raspbian Buster anyway but instead is about [Debian Buster for Raspberry Pi 3](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3).